# Node fast way to find in array

Tags: arrays, node.js

I have a Problem.

My script was working fine and fast, when there was only like up to 5000 Objects in my Array.

Now there over 20.000 Objects and it runs slower and slower...

This is how i called it

```
    for(var h in ItemsCases) {
        if(itmID == ItemsCases[h].sku) {
```

With "for" for every object and check where the sku is my itmID, cause i dont want every ItemsCases. Only few of it each time.

But what is the fastest and best way to get the items with the sku i need out of it?

I think mine, is not the fastest...

I get multiple items now with that code

```
var skus = res.response.cases[x].skus;
for(var j in skus) {
    var itmID = skus[j];
    for(var h in ItemsCases) {
        if(itmID == ItemsCases[h].sku) {
```

the skus is also an array

Comment: That depends on your query. Do you always search using `itmID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ItemsCases.find(item => item.sku === itmID)` (or a `for` loop like yours, depending on the implementation) is the fastest you can do with an array (if you can have multiple items returned, use `filter` instead of `find`).

Use a `Map` or an object lookup if you need to be faster than that. It does need preparation and memory, but if you are searching a lot it may well be worth it. For example, using a `Map`:

```
// preparation of the lookup
const ItemsCasesLookup = new Map();
ItemsCases.forEach(item => {
  const list = ItemsCasesLookup.get(item.sku);
  if (list) {
    list.push(item)
  } else {
    ItemsCasesLookup.set(item.sku, [item]);
  }
});
```

then later you can get all items for the same sku like this:

```
ItemsCasesLookup.get(itmID);
```

A compromise (not more memory, but some speedup) can be achieved by pre-sorting your array, then using a binary search on it, which is much faster than linear search you have to do on an unprepared array.

Comment: `===`, not `==`.

Comment: Its slower than mine with that find way... Can you show me example for map?

Comment: Then you're stuck at your current speed unless you prepare your data.

Comment: I can, if you tell me whether you only have one item per sku, or multiple items can share a sku. Also, if the array is fixed, or you change stuff in it.

Comment: I need multiple items, check on my thread post, i show you more code there... I have the (also an array) and i have the items which must compare to the array skus

Comment: Thanks! With Map it looks like a sec faster... i had around 2.5s before, now its around 1.5s.

Comment: If you're doing it several times with the same array, the savings are bigger, as you only need to prepare the lookup once.

Comment: @Rajesh: I have no idea what the key is, it is not in the question; given that, I chose to go the safer route. Object was also suggested, and the implementation is completely parallel, so if OP prefers it, they are free to do so.

Comment: @Amadan I have updated the [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/array-search-comparison) link to use Map. That should give users clear comparison in addition to your answer.

Comment: @Rajesh I'm afraid those tests don't make much sense, as you are doing prep work inside the benchmark, which is not informative. If you are worried about the start-up cost, there needs to be a separate benchmark for start-up, and a separate one for search itself.